# Objective C Objects Only Being Changed In Method Scope

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am making a chat application, and when the person logs onto the chat successfully, the server replies with the people that are online at that moment. That string (the server sends a string) gets converted to a NSMutableArray, which is then stored into a NSMutableArray called `tableData`, which is the data source for a NSTableView. When the online people are stored into `tableData`, the NSLog output shows that `tableData` is filled. However, when that method is done, and the login view is closed, in the debugger `tableData` says `0 Objects`, and the NSTableView doesn't fill, which it normally does. Here is are my methods (one calls another):

```
- (void)getPeople:(NSString *)outputMessage
{
    NSArray *newTableData = [outputMessage componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newTableData];
    //[self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:0];;
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", self.tableData);
    [self.people reloadData];
}

- (void)accessGrantedWithOnlineUsers:(NSString *)users
{
    NSLog(@"Access Granted");
    self.isLoggedIn = YES;
    [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Logout"];
    [self getPeople:users];
}
```

Here is my method that opens and closes the login view:

```
- (IBAction)loginToChat:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called");
    if (self.loginPopover == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is nil");
        self.loginPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
        self.loginPopover.contentViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    if (!self.loginPopover.isShown) {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is opening");
        [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [self.settingsButton setEnabled:NO];
        [self.send setEnabled:NO];
        [self.message setEnabled:NO];
        [self.loginPopover showRelativeToRect:self.loginButton.frame ofView:self.view preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Login Popover is closing");
        if (self.isLoggedIn) {
            [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Logout"];
        }
        else {
            [self.loginButton setTitle:@"Login"];
        }
        [self.settingsButton setEnabled:YES];
        [self.send setEnabled:YES];
        [self.message setEnabled:YES];
        [self.loginPopover close];
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have a deadline for this project.

Comment: So how many different instances of your class do you create?

Comment: Which class @HotLicks

Comment: The class that these are all part of is a nsviewcontroller.

Comment: check your code to make sure you're not doing something like `self.tableData = [ NSMutableArray array ]` or `[ self.tableData removeAllObjects ]`. Also is it possible `getPeople:` is being called more than once (with a `nil` or empty string argument)?

Comment: The class that "owns" your problem array.

Comment: I have a breakpoint on getpeople so it is only being called once

Comment: How many different placed do you alloc/init your class?  There should only be one.

Comment: I dont alloc init the view controller.

Comment: Wait actually i do once

Comment: It is a ns view that drops down from the menu bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newTableData];
```

can you try

```
self.tableData = [newTableData copy];
```

The only thing i can think of is - is the tableData a strong property?

Comment: Yes it is a strong property `(strong, nonatomic)`

Comment: Did you try changing newTableData copy?

Comment: Does it say "Data: 0 objects" ?

Comment: It says `_tableData = (_NSArrayM *) @"0 Objects`

Comment: Is that the debugger. Sometimes, its wierd. Can you put a breakpoint and in your lldb console type p tableData.count

Comment: Did you print "p tableData.count", what was the result?

Comment: `(unsigned long long) $0 = 15` the login window was open and `(unsigned long long) $1 = 0` after i closed it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39388/discussion-between-insert-name-here-and-pradeep-mahdevu)

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:newTableData];
```

write this snippet:

```
[self setTableData:tableData]
```

Comment: @insert Name Here  are you able to print array using above snippet?

Comment: it successfully changes the array for that scope but still after that method is over and the loginview is closed it doesn't worl